# Serialized Object File Output is empty

Tags: java, arrays, file, serialization

I am trying to create a file that stores high scores for a game that I am making. I am using a serializer to write my arrays into a file. The file is created upon running my code but the file is empty (0 bytes). I'm not getting any errors. Can anyone tell me why the file does not contain my data?

```
public class BestTimes implements Serializable
{
    BestTimes[] beginner = new BestTimes[2];

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BestTimes bestTimes = new BestTimes();
        bestTimes.outputToFile();
    }

    public BestTimes() {
        beginner[0] = new BestTimes(1, "John", 10.5);
        beginner[1] = new BestTimes(2, "James", 20.3);
    }

    public int ranking;
    public String playerName;
    public double time;

    public BestTimes(int r, String p, double t) 
    {
        ranking = r;
        playerName = p;
        time = t;
    }

    public void outputToFile() throws IOException {
        try(FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("bestTimes.txt")) {
            ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
            s.writeObject(beginner);
            s.flush();
            s.close();
        } finally {
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("bestTimes.txt");
            f.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: To anyone who may have downvoted my question, I'm sorry if I did something wrong with my question. I would appreciate feedback telling me what is wrong with my question rather than just downvoting it. That way I won't make the same mistakes with future questions.

Comment: `FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("bestTimes.txt");
            f.close();
` - this opens the file and deletes its contents, then closes it again. So you successfully write the file, then you overwrite it with nothing.

Comment: Sorry I had put in that piece of code because of a misunderstanding of an answer to a previous question.

Comment: @kb400 I shortend your sample code somewhat, no point in repeating dozent of sample records if it shows the problem with one or two. This way problems is found quicker if you do not need to scroll.

Comment: @eckes Thank you. That does make it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's empty. You created a new one in the `finally` block.

Just remove that code.